# Write INI files with comment lines using TiniFile class

Tags: delphi, ini

Can I use the **`TIniFile`** class from Delphi in any way to write comments to my INI files ?

```
[VALUES]
; first number
a=5
; something else
b=25
...
...
```

In the examples  ([EXAMPLE](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/tinifile.htm)) I found on the web there are sometimes nice comment lines added, but not shown how to create, read , write these lines  ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TIniFile` class is a loose wrapper around the Windows API functions the provide INI file services. That API does not support writing comments and so `TIniFile` cannot do so either.

If you want to emit files with comments, you will have to find a different INI file library, or roll your own.

Comment: As of Delphi 10, TMemIniFile is fully implemented with TStrings and dictionaries, but still does not support comments.

Comment: @Eric Although the question, and therefore my answer, relate to `TIniFile` rather than `TMemIniFile`

Answer (score 5):

Neither `TIniFile` or `TMemIniFile` supports reading or writing INI file comments.

If you need to add or retrieve comments, you'll need to use a `TStringList` instead, and use the `Names` and `Values` functionality to read and write values. You can save the file with `SaveToFile` and load it with `LoadFromFile`, but it takes more work to handle the default values and various `ReadXX` methods yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do it with TIniFile:

```
WriteString('Section', '; Comment'#13#10 + 'Name', 'Value');
```

Here's with a check that the value doesn't exist:

```
if ReadString('Section', 'Name', #13#10) = #13#10 then
  WriteString('Section', '; Comment'#13#10 + 'Name', 'Value');
```

(TIniFile has ValueExists function, but it reads the whole section and searches for the key. I prefer this small check.)

Comment: Great solution! You can even use this approach to insert empty lines above an entry: `WriteString('Section', #13#10 + 'Name', 'Value');`

Answer (score 1):

Only can suggest use WriteString like following:

```
ini.WriteString('VALUES','; first number','');
```

The result is not exactly the same you expected, but anyway you will be able to add some comments.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a old question, but i'll add my funcion to add comment to ini file. Fell free to improve . 
Sorry about grammar mistakes.English is not my primary language

```
class Procedure TCoreIniAsTextFile.AddComment(ini: TiniFile; Comment: array of string; Section: string = ''; Key: string = '');
Const
  LIST_NUMERIC_SIZE: Integer = 3;
var
  IniAsText         : Tstrings;
  i                 : Integer;
  j                 : Integer;
  Buffer            : string;
  // Method to remove previous comment
  Procedure WriteComment(StartLine: Integer);
var
  Linha             : Integer;
  LinBuf            : string;
begin
  repeat
    // add a space to avoid a except in the following line
    // if a line is blank
    LinBuf := Trim(IniAsText[StartLine]) + ' ';
    if LinBuf[1] = ';' then // is a comment
      IniAsText.Delete(StartLine);
  until (LinBuf[1] <> ';') or (IniAsText.Count = 0);
  // add new comment
  for Linha := High(Comment) downto Low(Comment) do
    begin
      IniAsText.Insert(StartLine, ';' + Comment[Linha]);
    end;

  IniAsText.Insert(StartLine, ''); // add a line for esthetic purposes  
  IniAsText.SaveToFile(ini.FileName);
end;
// function to add zeros to left 1 -> 001
function StrZeroReg(num: Int64; nsize: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(num);
  Result := StringOfChar('0', nsize - Length(Result)) + Result;
end;  
begin
  IniAsText := nil; // to avoid a warning below
  Section := Uppercase(Section);
  Key := Uppercase(Key);
  try
    IniAsText := TStringList.Create;
    if not FileExists(ini.FileName) then
      IniAsText.SaveToFile(ini.FileName);  // Create a blank file 

    IniAsText.LoadFromFile(ini.FileName);

    // If no section or key direct comment to file header
    if (Section = EmptyStr) and (Key = EmptyStr) then
      begin
        WriteComment(0);
        Exit;
      end;

    // If key is passed section is required 
    if (Section = EmptyStr) and (Key <> EmptyStr) then
      begin
        if not ini.SectionExists(Section) then
          raise Exception.Create('Section is required to write key comment');
      end;

    //If section is passed, but not key assume coment is to section 
    if (Section <> EmptyStr) and (Key = EmptyStr) then
      begin
        // section must exists
        if not ini.SectionExists(Section) then
          raise Exception.Create('Section ' + Section + ' does not exists');

        // search for section location in file 
        for i := 0 to IniAsText.Count - 1 do
          begin
            Buffer := Trim(Uppercase(IniAsText[i]));
            if (Buffer = '[' + Section + ']') then
              begin
                WriteComment(i);
                Exit;
              end;
          end;

        // sanity check
        raise Exception.Create('Section ' + Section + ' does not exists');
        exit;
      end;

    // If key and section is passed assume is a key comment
    if not ini.ValueExists(Section, Key) then
      begin

        // some ini libraries save stringlists to ini and save values as
        // valuea001,valuea002,...,valueannn . then search KEY000 as compatibility
        if ini.ValueExists(Section, Key + StrZeroReg(0, LIST_NUMERIC_PALCES)) then
          Key := Key + StrZeroReg(0, LIST_NUMERIC_PALCES)
        else // if not found Key000
          raise Exception.Create('KEY ' + Section + '\' + Key + ' does not exists');
      end;

    // search combination of section + key 
    for i := 0 to IniAsText.Count - 1 do
      begin
        Buffer := Trim(Uppercase(IniAsText[i]));
        if (Buffer = '[' + Section + ']') then
          begin
            for j := i + 1 to IniAsText.Count - 1 do
              begin
                Buffer := Trim(Uppercase(IniAsText[j])) + ' '; // space to avoid a exception 
                // Buffer[1] <> ';' to avoid commented lines 
                // Key + '=', Buffer) = 1 to avoid false cognats but will fail if param is 
                // param =value (valid to some libraries)
                if (Buffer[1] <> ';') and (Pos(Key + '=', Buffer) = 1) then
                  begin
                    WriteComment(j);
                    Exit;
                  end;
              end
          end;
      end;

  finally
    if Assigned(IniAsText) then
      IniAsText.Free;
  end;
end;
```