# Using ini-file-comments with TIniFile-ReadSection with Lazarus/FreePascal

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

using [`TIniFile.ReadSectionValues`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/inifiles/tinifile.readsection.html) with Lazarus/FreePascal I (thought) I shouldn't get a comments (with ";" in at the beginning of the line in an ini-file) as an output. Using [`TIniFile.ReadSectionValuesRaw`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/inifiles/tinifile.readsectionraw.html) I should. But the following code snippet which uses `TIniFile.ReadSectionValues` also reads the comment lines, why is that? Thx!

```
var iniFile : TINIFile; 
var strList : TStringList; 
var intIndex : Integer; 

iniFile := TINIFile.Create('TaskMaster.ini');
strList := TStringList.Create;
iniFile.ReadSectionValues('IniSection',strList);
for intIndex := 0 to strList.Count - 1 do begin
    ShowMessage (strList.strings[intIndex]);
    end;
iniFile.Free;
strList.Free;
```

Here's the ini-File:

```
[IniSection]
test1=something
;test2=something else
; test3=still something else
```

according to this [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867210/write-ini-files-with-comment-lines-using-tinifile-class) comments don't work, but the doc for  [`ReadSectionValues`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/inifiles/tinifile.readsection.html) and  [`ReadSectionValuesRaw`](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/inifiles/tinifile.readsectionraw.html) brings me to a different understanding.

Comment: Can not reproduce here, but try `iniFile := TINIFile.Create('TaskMaster.ini', [ifoStripComments]);`

Comment: @Abelisto that notation doesn't work (`Error: Identifier not found "ifoStripComments"`), can you actually use it within the `TINIFile.Create` statement or do you have to create a new `TCustomIniFileoption` instance?

Comment: It seems that you are using outdated FPC. As I understand `TIniFileOption` type and constructor `Create(const AFileName: string; AOptions : TIniFileOptions = []);` was introduced in the 3.0.2 release: https://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/tags/release_3_0_2/packages/fcl-base/src/inifiles.pp

Comment: @Abelisto yeah, your are right, I'm still using 3.0.0

Comment: @Abelisto if you like you can post it as the answer so I can accept it

Comment: Suggesting to update your software is not the acceptable answer here. Just use latest release of FPC/Lasarus (I using trunk versions BTW it is funny at least and it is why I can not to post answers: something that working on my playground probably will not working on the release version) Good luck! :)

Comment: @Abelisto thanks. I haven't really updated Lazarus yet. Is there a chance of something going wrong? I think I would rather have a second updated version installed. Do you know if this is possible? PS. just found a [solution](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Multiple_Lazarus#Who_needs_multiple_Lazarus_instances_and_who_does_not.3F) unless you know a better way...  PPS. On a sidenote if the missing "update" is the problem I'm wondering why that answer isn't acceptable

Comment: Something always going wrong :) It is really up to you, but I figure to update your environment at least to the latest release of FPC/Lazarus is the good thing (as I said above I using trunk and yes I have some problems but when I send my code to product it already became from trunk to stable)

Comment: @Abelisto thanks...  good point. Haven't tried to install the second instance yet, maybe I'll do a test run on a virtual machine first.